# Why are questions about recommendations of pieces to play off topic?

Tags: discussion

Why are [these](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/12482/seeking-a-piece-or-study-melodic-minor/12497#12497) type of questions off topic?

I think that some questions that ask for recommendations of pieces to play might be useful to future readers.

For instance:

--I just started playing electric guitar/bass/drums and I'm really into rock/metal/punk, what are some beginner songs I can practice?

--I'm learning piano for some time now, but I've only been learning chords/intervals and some basic exercises (which are boring). Are there some simple songs that I could play?

The latter is something that has happened to me when I started playing double bass, and I believe it would be good if I had some simple songs to play back then.

Comment: Essentially because [Stack Exchange is not designed for lists](http://meta.music.stackexchange.com/q/161/28).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two reasons:

- As Matthew pointed out, you will just get a series of answers, all of which may be correct in one way or other, and lists are not what Stack Exchange is all about
- It is quite subjective which pieces/songs/tracks will suit you. Even professional schools teach different tracks, so a bunch of enthusiasts on the internet will definitely have differing opinions